# Finding $E(Y^2)$ of moment generating function of Binomial Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

$$E[Y^2] = m''(t), t=0$$
$$= np(p+q)^{n-2}(q+np)$$
$$=np(q+np)$$

I am wondering how to obtain line 3 from line 2?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: $p+q=1\,\,\,\,$

Comment: Is your problem solved?